# Java - byte[] to String and then back to byte[]

Tags: java, string, arrays

I have to put a `byte[]` into a string , then convert it back to a `byte]` .

However when I'm doing so , the returning `byte[]` is different from the original one .

This is the code :

```
public class HelloWorld {            
  public static void main(String[] args) {        
    byte[] data = {
            (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12,
            (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12,
        };

    System.out.println("OriginalDataByte : " + data);

    String datastring = data.toString();

    System.out.println("StringFromByteArray : " + datastring);

    byte[] newdata = datastring.getBytes();

    System.out.println("ByteArrayFromString: " + newdata);                        
  }
}
```

Returning :

```
OriginalDataByte : [B@6d06d69c
StringFromByteArray : [B@6d06d69c
ByteArrayFromString: [B@7852e922
```

Any way to fix this ?

Comment: Your question title is incorrect.  In Java `Byte[]` and `byte[]` are different things.  Are you really asking about `byte[]` or `Byte[]`?  Many other confusions in your question too.  But it >>looks<< like the real problem is that you don't understand what `toString()` prints for an array.

Comment: Please don't mutilate your question, even if it turns out you made a mistake. I have reverted your edit.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `toString()` in a **primitive array reference**, which is printing the hashcode of the reference along with type.

You should we using `String(byte[])` constructor for creating String from byte array. instead of `data.toString()`.

```
String datastring = new String(data);
System.out.println("StringFromByteArray : " + datastring);
```

The `getBytes()` from the string will return you a new `byte[]`, with the content of string as bytes.

```
byte[] newdata = datastring.getBytes();
```

So the `newData` and `data` will be referring to two different objects. In java primitive arrays are objects.

Comment: i made the changes but it still does not work . returning http://i.imgur.com/4aak7z8.png

Comment: @Jimmy Yes, That is correct, Do you know what is the hex content you are providing here?

Comment: https://ideone.com/yDgWja

Answer (score 1):

toString of Byte Array usage Object's toString method and returns `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

And this never convert back to your original byte array data . Following code is correct bay to convert into string and get back byte array.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        byte[] data = {
            (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12,
            (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12,};

        System.out.println("OriginalDataByte : " + data);
        System.out.println("OriginalDataByte string: " + new String(data));

        String datastring = new String(data);

        System.out.println("StringFromByteArray : " + datastring);

        byte[] newdata = datastring.getBytes();

        System.out.println("ByteArrayFromString: " + new String(newdata));
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working  : https://ideone.com/TaLff7

Answer (score 0):

When you convert a `byte[]` to a `String`, you are implicitly *decoding* it from some charset + character encoding scheme into (in effect) UTF-16.  When you concert the `String` to a `byte[]`, you are implicitly *encoding* from UTF-16 into the aforementioned encoding.

The problem is that if you don't specify a `Charset` (or charset name) when you do the conversions, you will get the platform's *default* `Charset`.  And that is a problem because *most* character sets do not allow you to convert an arbitrary byte sequence into a string and back again without some data loss.

> Any way to fix this ?

It happens that the LATIN-1 character encoding does map all 256 bytes into a unique Unicode codepoint, and the decode / encode sequence is lossless.  So one solution would be to use `"LATIN-1"` as the charset name in the conversions.

However, in my opinion what you are doing here is conceptually wrong.  The `String` class is designed for holding sequences of *characters* ... not arbitrary binary data.

Comment: I tried using : String datastring = new String(data , "UTF-8");   and data.getBytes("UTF-8")  ..but it doesnt recognize the charset type

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt recognize the charset type"?  You have given it a `String` not a `Charset`.  Also, using UTF-8 is unlikely to work ... unless the byte array contains genuine UTF-8 encoded text.